# Associate contact activity with lead

Tags: apex, contact, activity, activityhistory

please tell me how it is possible to associate the activity of a contact with a lead or other contact in the code.
My task is to convert a contact into a lead and I need to transfer all the information.
Thanks for any advice!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Task object has two polymorphic lookups (i.e. that can point to more than one type of records):

- `WhoId`, which can point to a Lead or a Contact record
- `WhatId`, which can point to other records, typically Account or Opportunity records, but also custom objects and, in general, most objects *other than* Lead or Contact

If we are just using those two lookups, if a Task is associated to a Contact, it is impossible to associate it to a Lead or to another Contact at the same time.

If your org has Shared Activities enabled (h/t [Mariia Illarionova](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/62973/mariia-illarionova), see comments below) it is possible to partially bypass that limitation using [TaskRelation records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_taskrelation.htm). This allows you to connect an Activity record to *either* one Lead or 50 Contact records. Note that, similar to the previous case, if an activity is linked to a Lead, it cannot be associated to another Contact.

Separately, bear in mind that there are situations in which the transfer of tasks between records is designed to happen seamlessly. Suppose that we are converting Lead L into Contact C (preexisting or newly created, it does not matter), or suppose that we are merging Contact C1 into Contact C2. In those scenarios, any Task records hanging from L or C1 will be transferred to C or C2, respectively.

Comment: About task having multiple associated contacts: you are wrong. Setup -> Activity Settings -> Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events -> TRUE. This allows you to associate task with up to 50 contacts through `TaskRelation`. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.activities_enable_shared_activities.htm&type=5

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova —True! I had forgotten about that one! Amending the answer.